# How do I add bytearrays to doctests?

Tags: python, arrays, doctest

This is my function signature,

```
def fun12(bytes_var: bytearray, signed: bool) -> (int):
```

When I do,

`print(fun12(b'\x00\x10',False))`

My code works just fine, but when I have something like the following in my doctest comments,

```
>>> fun12(b'\x00\x10',False)
16
```

I get an error,

```
Failed example:
    fun12(b'',False)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/usr12/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/doctest.py", line 1348, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
    ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in __main__
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

It seems as though I can't send byte array values to a dockets function, but how else can I specify my test cases?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but please note, `b'123'` is a `bytes` object, not a `bytearray`, they are different types. `bytes` are immutable while `bytearray` is mutable.

Comment: Try `>>> fun12(bytearray([0,32]),False)`

Comment: @RootTwo Yes,that gives an output, but its not 16

Comment: @mousetail Oh Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the test is being typed as **part of a string**. Writing something like

```
"""
>>> fun12(b'\x00\x10',False)
16
"""
```

creates a string that **actually contains** a null character (and a character with Unicode code point 16), not the Python source code for a `bytes` literal.

Therefore, the backslashes need to be escaped:

```
"""
>>> fun12(b'\\x00\\x10',False)
16
"""
```

This way, the docstring actually contains a backslash, lowercase x, etc., such that *when the string is interpreted as Python source code*, it creates the desired `bytes` object.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prevent escaping characters is to make the string raw:

This will create a null byte which is invalid inside byte strings (it needs to be escaped)

```py
def a():
   """
   print(b'\x00')
   """

print(a.__doc__)
# prints "print(b'�')" where � is a null byte
```

This will create a string containing `\x00` which is valid python code:

```py
def b():
   r"""
   print(b'\x00')
   """ #notice the r before the """

print(b.__doc__)
# prints "print(b'\x00')"
```